# jsp txt file download gives me jsp content

Tags: java, jsp

i have a jsp project , in my project i want to download a txt file from the location.The code really worked but the conent of the file is actually jsp index page content, i don't know how is this happened.

```
    String filename = "Teste.txt";   
  String filepath = "D:\\Online Secure File Transfer System\\project";   
  response.setContentType("APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM");   
  response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=\"" + filename + "\"");   

  java.io.FileInputStream fileInputStream=new java.io.FileInputStream(filepath + filename);  

  int i;   
  while ((i=fileInputStream.read()) != -1) {  
    out.write(i);   
  }   
  fileInputStream.close();
```

Comment: could you please tell me clearly?

Comment: your file path is not good

Comment: the download is really happening, but the content is not what i expected.
the data is from index.jsp file .

Comment: where do you download from?

Comment: you read this link :http://www.codejava.net/java-ee/servlet/java-servlet-download-file-example

Comment: i downloaded from the location mentioned in the question.

Comment: honestly you code should work as intended, maybe its  a server caching issue, however  If you want to make sure you could try to create a link to your file `<a href= "D/Online Secure File Transfer System/project/teste.txt"> yourFile </a>`

Comment: problem is with you file path : e:/ test/t1.txt

Comment: you give total file path like this : java.io.FileInputStream fileInputStream=new java.io.FileInputStream(filepath);

Answer (score 1):

I think problem with your file path , do not append string

```
  String filename = "Teste.txt"; 
  String filepath = "D:\\Online Secure File Transfer System\\project\\Teste.txt";   
  response.setContentType("APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM");   
  response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=\"" + filename + "\"");   
  java.io.FileInputStream fileInputStream=new java.io.FileInputStream(filepath);  

  int i;   
  while ((i=fileInputStream.read()) != -1) {  
    out.write(i);   
  }   
  fileInputStream.close();
```

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link href="images/favicon/lock_ok.ico" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon"/>
        <title>ONLINE SECURE FILE TRANSFER</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        cjflkjf;
    </body>
</html>
i get the file content inside html tags.

Comment: much better now. but the actual text inside html tag.